# Set limit per user to view posts in django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('User')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=320)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I want to Get newest posts which just show 3 or less posts per day from each user, For example :

```
User1 published 3 posts today.
User2 published 20 posts today.
```

I want a Django ORM command that limit to show just 3 posts each user per day. 
This query should get 6 posts:

```
3 posts from Users1
3 posts from Users2
```

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi I have no idea how do it ? I think about annote but i want orderby post by `created_date` but I have to limit posts for each user ...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the optimal solution but something like this should achieve what you are trying to do.

```
posts = []
for user in User.objects.all():
    posts.append(Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-created_date')[:3])
```

Comment: It takes a lot of time to execute this query. I solve it with row_number in postgres but unfortunately django orm doesn't have it.